# urxvt: Open graphical file explorer in the current folder

Tags: perl, urxvt

While the command line is very useful for most of the tasks, I sometimes resort to a graphical file explorer (like Nautilus, Thunar, PCmanFM). I would like a keyboard shortcut or a context-menu entry to open such a graphical file explorer _in the current directory. I know the converse is possible with `nautilus-open-terminal`. Is there currently a way to do that?

It may require writing a perl-extension, but I do not know enough of perl and urxvt to find how to capture the current `PWD`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Bash as your shell, here's an alias you could add to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias nh="nautilus file://$(pwd)"
```

I called it `nh` for "Nautilus here".  So from the comman-line you would simply type:

```
nh
```

for a nautilus window in the shell's current directory.

I have no idea what's involved in adding something to the urxvt context menu - sorry.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the idea! However, and I should have added that in the question, my idea is to not "disturb" the current shell session by launching a tied command inside (if I close the term, Nautilus would close too).

Comment: Are you sure about that? If run `nautilus` from the command-line in a `gnome-terminal` window, it fires up an entirely independent file manager window - which continues to run if I close the terminal. If `urxvt` doesn't do that for you, then you can probably workaround it by using `nohup` in the alias.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I quickly hacked a small extension to do this: https://github.com/raphaelfournier/urxvt-perl.

The opening of the file browser can be triggered with the right-click menu or a keyboard shortcut. The selection can be a directory, but also a filename, which will then be opened by the application associated with it in the file browser.